# Github integration with Jenkins- github credentials not getting added in jenkins UI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have been trying to integrate jenkins with github using Jenkin's Github Plugin. My intension is to trigger a build whenever anything is pushed to master branch in github repo. I am following the instruction written on one of the blog (url http://nepalonrails.tumblr.com/post/14217655627/set-up-jenkins-ci-on-ubuntu-for-painless-rails3).

I am not able to add the Github credentials in "GitHub Plugin Configuration". There are no options available in the crdentials dropdown.

[image: Initial State: No credential Added]

I clicked the "Add" button and filled the form opened in overlay. I saved it.

[image: Added Credentials Here]

I still don't get the credentials added in previous step in the dropdown. And when I attempt "Verify Credentials", it is still having the error.

[image: Still no value in dropdown]

I am not sure, what am i doing wrong. Here are other details if it matters-

Jenkins Version: 1.652

Java version "1.7.0_95"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

git version 1.9.1

I am sharing the error log /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log-

On Git commit and push-

> Mar 11, 2016 12:40:46 PM
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.subscriber.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber
>   onEvent INFO: Received POST for
>   https://github.com//

On attempt to save the credentials in pop-up-

> Mar 11, 2016 12:29:00 PM
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.internal.GitHubLoginFunction
>   applyNullSafe WARNING: Failed to login with creds 
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.github.com/user    at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:240)
>     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
>     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
>     at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:483)   at
>   org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:236)  at
>   org.kohsuke.github.Requester.to(Requester.java:203)   at
>   org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.getMyself(GitHub.java:276)  at
>   org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.(GitHub.java:143)     at
>   org.kohsuke.github.GitHubBuilder.build(GitHubBuilder.java:196)    at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.internal.GitHubLoginFunction.applyNullSafe(GitHubLoginFunction.java:73)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.internal.GitHubLoginFunction.applyNullSafe(GitHubLoginFunction.java:46)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.util.misc.NullSafeFunction.apply(NullSafeFunction.java:18)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.config.GitHubServerConfig$DescriptorImpl.doVerifyCredentials(GitHubServerConfig.java:297)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:324)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:167)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:100)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:124)   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:233)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:49)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
>     at
>   hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
>     at
>   hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
>     at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>     at
>   winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? I have had issue with Jenkins not displaying things correctly in the past..

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE , I tried it in the latest version of Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the credentials under global jenkins configuration, and the credentials are for the github request builder plugin.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a token on github and then use "Secret Text" and not "Username with password" when creating your login in Jenkins.